# SQL Select for create daily log data from more than one date column frrom a single table

Tags: sql-server, date, select

I have a table with more than one date column,
each date column hold a date or null value,

I want to write a SQL query which will display each column have date into a new row with a new additional column named LogDate that contain the same date of column.


Its difficult to explain, please referrer the attached image.


[image]

Comment: Is the order of the three sets important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `UNION ALL` to concatenate the three result sets:

```
SELECT [ReceivedDate] AS LogDate, * FROM MyTable WHERE [ReceivedDate] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [Closing Date] AS LogDate, * FROM MyTable WHERE [Closing Date] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [LPODate] AS LogDate, * FROM MyTable WHERE [LPODate] IS NOT NULL
```

To sort by LogDate simply add the following ORDER BY clause to the end of this query:

```
ORDER BY LogDate
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Though, I would add alias to table for each statement and in the select statement: SELECT t.*, t.[...Date] as LogDate (since it requested all columns of the table + additional).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the * after each `LogDate` column. However, there's no need to alias each table as you don't need to reference them anywhere.

Comment: Yes, that was what i was looking for. One more question after union how will i sort the LogDate.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY LogDate`.